# django queryset to output foreignkey objects to ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class Location(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Point(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   location = models.ForeignKey('Location')
```

I have a list of locations:

```
Location A
Location B
Location C
```

Every Point belongs to a location:

```
Point 1 -> Location A
Point 2 -> Location B
```

I want to provide a queryset to a forms.ModelChoiceField so that it shows only Locations which have a Point associated in the database (in the example above it should only return Location A and Location B).

In SQL language it would be:
SELECT location.* FROM location JOIN point ON location.id = punto.location_id

I've spent the last two hours reading the Django documentation, but I couldn't find any method to do what I need... any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query with:

```
Location.objects.filter(point__isnull=False).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) is strictly speaking not necessary, but without the `.distinct()` you will retrieve each `Location` that many times as their are related `Point`s in the database.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware I could use that reverse reference in the filter!

Comment: @MattiaVerga: Yes. Django will always automatically add a (conceptual) relation in reverse (unless you explicitly disable this).